# Convert string into vector in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, vector, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have two PySpark dataframes of the following structure. I would like to perform cross join and calculate cosine similarity. The qry_emb is a string column with comma separated values.

How to convert this string into dense vector?

[image: Pyspark dataframe]

```py
df.printSchema()
# root
# |-- query: string (nullable = true)
# |-- qry_emb: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert string to vector, first convert your string to array ([`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split)), then use [`array_to_vector`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.functions.array_to_vector.html)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.ml.functions import array_to_vector
df = df.withColumn('qry_emb', array_to_vector(F.split('qry_emb', ',[ ]*').cast('array<double>')))
```